# ortools: How to use search strategies sweep and best insertion?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I want to solve routing problems with the `SWEEP` or `BEST_INSERTION` strategies:

```
search_params = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()
strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.SWEEP
search_params.first_solution_strategy = strategy
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_params)
```

does not find an assignment and prints

> E0502 16:25:38.036972 15475 routing.cc:1604] Undefined sweep arranger
>   for ROUTING_SWEEP strategy.

to the screen. How do I define the "sweep arranger"?

```
strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.BEST_INSERTION
```

also returns no assignment and doesn't tell me why either.

Comment: This question might be very old, but... for the BEST_INSERTION method the documentation says: *As of 2/2012, only works on models with optional nodes (with finite penalty costs).* Maybe if it's not your case it crashes (I tried with C++ and it gives me a segmentation fault).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SetSweepArranger](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L804) which unfortunately is not exported (i.e. swig wrapped) in python...

Comment: how can I use it then? Is there a workaround? Also, because I am curious, why is it not exported?